# How to scroll beyond last line in MSWord?

Tags: microsoft-word, scrolling

In `MSWord` when using the `web layout` view is there an option to allow scrolling beyong the last line?

For instance I am working on a long list of items using the web layout.  As my document grows larger than the height of my computer screen the last insertion point is constantly at the bottom.  I would like to be able to scroll further down so that I can still see the last line at the top and blank filling up the rest of the space as when working on a new document, without having to manually insert a whole bunch of line breaks.  Possible?